# better way push array of an object to array of an object based on the same id?

Tags: javascript, lodash

hi I want to push array of an object to array of an object so the the new property will push to the array of object based on the same _id
this is the original data :

```
const data =[
             { 
              foo:foo1,
              data:{
                   _id:"a1",
                   man:2
                  }
            },
            { 
              foo:foo1,
              data:{
                   _id:"a1",
                   man:2
                }
             }
           ]
```

this is the data that I want to put on my original data

```
const d = [{
             _id:"a1",
             women:4,
           }]
```

And the desired output is:

```
      const data =[
             { 
              foo:foo1,
              data:{
                   _id:"a1",
                   man:2,
                   women:4
                  }
            },
            { 
              foo:foo1,
              data:{
                   _id:"a1",
                   man:2,
                   women:4
                }
             }
           ]
```

I think it can be done using for loop and check if the _id is the same and push it to the object, but is there any better way? or using lodash? any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you could just always add it and then use lodash unique on the updated array filter out all duplicates: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy. Not sure if this is slower performance than looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this!

```js
const d = [{
             _id:"a1",
             women:4,
           }
           ]
    
const data =[
             { 
              foo:"foo1",
              data:{
                   _id:"a1",
                   man:2
                  }
            },
            { 
              foo:"foo1",
              data:{
                   _id:"a1",
                   man:2
                }
             }
           ]    
var arr = data.map(function(obj, i){
    d.map(function(o,i){
    if(obj.data._id == o._id)
    {
        obj.data.women = o.women;
    }
    });
    return obj;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: hi matee, thanks for reply but im sorry there is misleading here , i want to push array of an object to array of an object and the const d should be an array

Comment: Hi bramasta, I have updated my answer please have a look, Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mateen , thank you for updating the code, I will accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

With the data structures you have you can loop through both and simply update the entries with the same `id`. That said this is a brute force solution with O(n^2) time complexity. This solution also returns a new object rather than mutating the original.

```
// Existing entries
const entries = [
    {
        data: {
            id: 'a1',
            man: 2
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: 'a1',
            man: 2
        }
    },
];

// Data with same id to update
const updates = [
    {
        id: 'a1',
        women: 4
    },
];

/**
 * Update properties for an existing entry given
 * a list of partially updated entries
 */
function updateEntries(entriesList, updatesList) {
    // Build up new array as to not mutate
    // the existing data structure
    const newEntries = [];
    for (const entry of entriesList) {
        for (const update of updatesList) {
            // Update when the ids match
            if (entry.data.id === update.id) {
                newEntries.push({
                    data: {
                        ...entry.data,
                        ...update
                    }
                });
            } else {
                newEntries.push(entry);
            }
        }
    }
    return newEntries;
}

const newEntries = updateEntries(entries, updates);
// newEntries = [
//     {
//         data: {
//             id: 'a1',
//             man: 2,
//             women: 4
//         }
//     },
//     {
//         data: {
//             id: 'a1',
//             man: 2,
//             women: 4
//         }
//     },
// ];
```

If you change your data structure for `entries` to be and object with each `entry` organized by `id` assuming they should actually be unique anyway, you can get O(n) based on `updates`.

```
// Entries by id
const entries = {
    a1: {
        man: 2
    },
    a2: {
        man: 2
    },
};
```

Comment: hi bradcush, thank you for reply , I already figure it out this way but i think this is not the best way to do it ,  is there a better way? maybe using lodash? thanks

Comment: If you have full control over the shape of your data for `entries` and `updates` the algorithm can be a bit simpler and it's possible you can leverage lodash to make this type of update more concise but it's definitely not needed.

Comment: Hi bradcush, thanks for the idea , i will look for that

Comment: I've also updated the answer to include what this alternative `entries` data structure could look like if your `entries` can be unique by `id`.